# Getting total values of a certain column from GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sql-server-2012, templatefield

Him

I am using a ASP.NET/VB.NET with SQL-Server-2012.

I have a a GridView column with 3 fields and 1 template field as shown below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Font-Names="Tahoma" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="item_name" HeaderText="Item" SortExpression="item_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="item_cost" HeaderText="Cost (inc. VAT)" SortExpression="item_cost" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="item_quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="item_quantity" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub-Total (inc. VAT)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("item_quantity")) * Convert.ToDouble(Eval("item_cost"))%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>                  
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class ProjectReport
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim ProjectID = Session("project_id")
        Session("ProjectID") = ProjectID

    End Sub
    Protected Sub grdItems_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        Dim totalPrice As Decimal = 0

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then


            Dim lblPrice As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalPrice"), Label)

            Dim price As Decimal = [Decimal].Parse(lblPrice.Text)


            totalPrice += price

        End If

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            Dim lblTotalPrice As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalPrice"), Label)

            lblTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString()


        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

**DataBound()**

```
   Private Sub BindData()

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim query As New SqlCommand("SELECT Items.item_name, Items.item_cost, project_items.item_quantity FROM Items INNER JOIN project_items ON items.item_id = project_items.item_id WHERE project_items.project_id = @parameter", conn)

        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session("ProjectID"))

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)

        da.SelectCommand = query

        Dim table As New DataTable()




        da.Fill(table)

        grdItems.DataSource = table
        grdItems.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

The last column (the template field) multiplies the quantity field with the cost field.

How do I calculate all the values (by adding) in the template field?

Comment: do you want to display the sum of in footer..

Comment: @Nag if possible yes!

Comment: Add a footertemplate and sum the value in ItemTemplate Label on `grdItems_RowDataBound`

Answer (score 1):

You must use the databinding events to sum the values. See [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35187/Summing-Columns-in-a-GridView) and adapt to your needs:

```
private Decimal OrderTotal;

protected void GridView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    OrderTotal = 0.0M;
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Keep adding the subtotal here
        OrderTotal += Subtotal;               
    }
}

protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    //Set a control with the total sum
    LabelOrderTotal.Text = OrderTotal.ToString("C");
}
```

Basically you keep adding the values in the `RowDataBound` event and in the `DataBound` event you set a label with the total sum. Alternatively, you can iterate over your grid in the `DataBound` event and add everything up.

Comment: Hi, I have follows the tutorial to no avail. I will update new code. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian You're missing the DataBound event. Read the example carefully

Comment: Please see updated code. I'm getting an error in 'query' telling me that an SqlCommand cannot be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

I personally would do it by performing the addition (as well as the multiplication actually) in the RowDataBound event...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all `DataRow` rows on the `DataBound` event of the gridview and add the value of TextBox3 to a running total variable.

```
Protected Sub grdItems_DataBound(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) 
    Dim row As GridViewRow = Nothing
    Dim runningTotal As Double = 0.0
    For i As Integer = 0 to grdItems.Rows.Count
        row = grdItems.Rows(i)
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            ' Add error handling here
            runningTotal += Ctype(CType(row.FindControl("TextBox3"), Label).Text, Double)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
decimal totalScore=0;
protected void gd__RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label TextBox3= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox3");                          

            decimal points = Decimal.Parse(TextBox3.Text);               

            totalScore += points;              
                        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
            lblTotal.Text = totalScore.ToString();                

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="first_name" SortExpression="first_name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_first_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("first_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label_first_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("first_name") %>'></asp:Label>      
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="middle_name" SortExpression="middle_name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_middle_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("middle_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label_middle_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("middle_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="last_name" SortExpression="last_name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_last_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("last_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label_last_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("last_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>


Protected Sub GridView_clients_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView_clients.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then

        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) 'gets the row

        '........................................

        Dim client_first_name As String = DirectCast(GridView_clients.Rows(index).FindControl("Label_first_name"), Label).Text.ToString
        Dim client_middle_name As String = DirectCast(GridView_clients.Rows(index).FindControl("Label_middle_name"), Label).Text.ToString
        Dim client_last_name As String = DirectCast(GridView_clients.Rows(index).FindControl("Label_last_name"), Label).Text.ToString


        'MsgBox(client_first_name)
        'MsgBox(client_middle_name)
        'MsgBox(client_last_name)

        lb_test.Text = client_first_name & " " & client_middle_name & " " & client_last_name

    End If

End Sub
```

from Craig Lewis Johnson from FSSA - Indiana